# Mean of groupby, after cut on variable

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I want to have a column which refers to the mean of variable X in a groupby, using only rows that pass a cut on variable Y.

I've done it with a bit of a workaround, so I'm wondering whether there is a more straighforward way to achieve this.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Animal': ['Falcon', 'Falcon', 'Falcon', 'Parrot', 'Parrot','Parrot'],
                   'Max_Speed': [380., 370., 90, 24., 100., 101]})

df['meanWithCut'] = df.query('Max_Speed>98').groupby('Animal').transform('mean')

df['meanWithCut'] = df.groupby('Animal')['meanWithCut'].apply(lambda x: x.fillna(x.max()))

df

    Animal  Max_Speed   meanWithCut
0   Falcon  380.0       375.0
1   Falcon  370.0       375.0
2   Falcon  90.0        375.0
3   Parrot  24.0        100.5
4   Parrot  100.0       100.5
5   Parrot  101.0       100.5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
df['meanWithCut'] = (df['Animal'].map(df.query('Max_Speed>98')
                    .groupby('Animal')['Max_Speed'].mean()))
print(df)
```

---

```
   Animal  Max_Speed  meanWithCut
0  Falcon      380.0        375.0
1  Falcon      370.0        375.0
2  Falcon       90.0        375.0
3  Parrot       24.0        100.5
4  Parrot      100.0        100.5
5  Parrot      101.0        100.5
```

Answer (score 2):

If you need filter before assign , I will do `agg` then map back

```
s = df.query('Max_Speed>98').groupby('Animal').agg('mean')
df['meanWithCut'] = s.reindex(df.Animal).values
df
Out[130]: 
   Animal  Max_Speed  meanWithCut
0  Falcon      380.0        375.0
1  Falcon      370.0        375.0
2  Falcon       90.0        375.0
3  Parrot       24.0        100.5
4  Parrot      100.0        100.5
5  Parrot      101.0        100.5
```

Push into to one

```
df['meanWithCut'] = df.query('Max_Speed>98').groupby('Animal').agg('mean').reindex(df.Animal).values
```